# Why does ThreadLocal utility always return null in Spring MVC app?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, thread-local

I wrote this utility class to save temporary data in a Spring MVC app:

```
public abstract class FooUtil {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> threadFoo = new ThreadLocal<String>();

    public static String getFooId(){
        return threadFoo.get();
    }

    public static void setFooId(String fooId){
        threadFoo.set(fooId);
    }

    public static void removeFooId(){
        threadFoo.remove();
    }

}
```

So I call `FooUtil.setFooId("foo")`.

But when I later call `FooUtil.getFooId()`, it always returns `null`.

Do I need a constructor? Or maybe this shouldn't be an abstract class? I don't know.

Comment: Maybe you simply call it from different threads?

Comment: Why would you do it like this?  What's the ThreadLocal buying you?  Nothing that I can see.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call getFooId from the same thread as setFooId.  This way you get the same result.
I would log the thread name when you set and get values to see if they are the same.

Comment: Can you give any example, how to call getFooId from the same thread as setFooId. I am suffering from the same issue. Please help me.

Comment: This is something you have to do in your design. The only thing you can do in code is to check which thread (e.g. by name) is doing a get/set and check they are the same.

Comment: Is there any way two persist ThreadLocal value as per session scope?

Comment: Actually I am using AbstractRoutingDataSource in spring application, where I need to rember current datasource selection by user. But in my case after some request ThreadLocal sets value to null.

Comment: It sounds like you want a session local variable.  You could use a synchronized WeakHashMap with the session as the key.