# Tomcat and thread creation

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm trying to understand threads in Tomcat.  I am working with a legacy JSP application which makes extensive use of ThreadLocals (initialised via a servlet filter when the application starts up).  I would like to convert the application to Spring MVC but I will need to do this gradually as it is quite a large application.

I'm having trouble accessing the data stored in the ThreadLocal's from my Spring MVC controllers.

[I now understand that I cannot access the data stored in a ThreadLocal in a different thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301794/why-does-threadlocal-utility-always-return-null-in-spring-mvc-app)

**Could somebody explain the Tomcat behaviour with regard to when it creates new threads?**

To demonstrate my issue I created a simple application with one servlet filter, one "standard" JSP, one Spring controller and one "Spring view" JSP.  Each component contains something like:

```
System.out.println("Spring JSP *** : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Running the web application using Maven (tomcat7:run) and clicking between the JSP and Spring view I get something like:

```html
Servlet Filter *** : http-bio-8080-exec-1
JSP *** : http-bio-8080-exec-1

Servlet Filter *** : http-bio-8080-exec-3
Spring Controller *** : http-bio-8080-exec-3
Spring JSP *** : http-bio-8080-exec-3

Servlet Filter *** : http-bio-8080-exec-4
JSP *** : http-bio-8080-exec-4

Servlet Filter *** : http-bio-8080-exec-5
Spring Controller *** : http-bio-8080-exec-5
Spring JSP *** : http-bio-8080-exec-5

Servlet Filter *** : http-bio-8080-exec-6
JSP *** : http-bio-8080-exec-6

Servlet Filter *** : http-bio-8080-exec-7
Spring Controller *** : http-bio-8080-exec-7
Spring JSP *** : http-bio-8080-exec-7

Servlet Filter *** : http-bio-8080-exec-8
JSP *** : http-bio-8080-exec-8

Servlet Filter *** : http-bio-8080-exec-9
Spring Controller *** : http-bio-8080-exec-9
Spring JSP *** : http-bio-8080-exec-9

Servlet Filter *** : http-bio-8080-exec-10
JSP *** : http-bio-8080-exec-10

Servlet Filter *** : http-bio-8080-exec-10
Spring Controller *** : http-bio-8080-exec-10
Spring JSP *** : http-bio-8080-exec-10

Servlet Filter *** : http-bio-8080-exec-10
JSP *** : http-bio-8080-exec-10

Servlet Filter *** : http-bio-8080-exec-10
Spring Controller *** : http-bio-8080-exec-10
Spring JSP *** : http-bio-8080-exec-10
```

As you can see, several different threads get created initially and then the thread usage between Spring and JSP/Filter tends to converge to a single thread.

I need Filter, JSPs and Spring MVC to share data in the same thread.
**What is the solution to this?**

Comment: Store the data in a request attribute, or in a ThreadLocal. As you saw, a given request is handled, from the filter to the JSP, by a unique thread.

Comment: [Servlet 3.0 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) explicitly states the requirement for a container to use the same thread for executing a filter and the subsequent servlet under section `6.2.3 Filter Environment`.  Although this was not clearly stated in earlier versions of the Servlet Specifications, Tomcat has long followed this and many popular frameworks have relied on this fact.  Therefore, one can safely use `ThreadLocal` variables to pass information from a filter to a servlet.